# can someone teach me how to read a Storyboard.TargetProperty and its transform group?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm a newbie looking at this example from 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199014/Page-Transition-Control-for-WPF

it has a lot storyboard objects such as this

`<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)" To="100" Duration="0:0:.75" AccelerationRatio=".9" />`

and a TransformGroup such as this

```
`<ScaleTransform 
  ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" 
  CenterX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource centerConverter}}" 
    CenterY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource centerConverter}}" 
/>

<SkewTransform 
  AngleX="0" 
  AngleY="0" 
    CenterX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource centerConverter}}" 
    CenterY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource centerConverter}}" 
/>

<RotateTransform 
  Angle="0" 
    CenterX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource centerConverter}}" 
    CenterY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource centerConverter}}" 
/>
<TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />`
```

Can someone explain how it works to me, this is SO CONFUSING! I've spent one whole day reading Xaml and wpf books, but i still don't get it. When I try understand by simplifying the code, i kept getting errors like this: '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(RenderTransform).(0)[1].(1)'

Is WPF really so DIFFICULT!?!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animations are probably not the best starting point if you're new to WPF, but I'll see if I can explain them a bit.

There are two types of "transforms" in WPF, which can be used to modify the appearance of a UI object.

- `LayoutTransform` modifies the object after WPF has determined how it's going to be laid out on the screen
- `RenderTransform` modifies the object after it has been rendered to the screen

Both of these properties contain a collection of [transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx) to occur for the object: `Rotate`, `Scale`, `Skew`, and `Translate` (move up/down or left/right)

An [Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) is something that changes a property from one value to another value over a specific period of time. For example, you might change the `Height` property of an object from 50 to 200 over a period of 1 second to make the object visibly grow bigger on the screen.

The code you are looking at is one of these animations.

```
<DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)" 
    To="100" Duration="0:0:.75" AccelerationRatio=".9" />
```

The tag name tells us it's a `DoubleAnimation`, meaning it is modifying a property that is of type `double`.

The `TargetProperty` tells us it is modifying the 2nd object in the `RenderTransform` collection (to simplify it a bit, `RenderTransform.Children[1]`)

The Transform expected there is a `SkewTransform`, and the animation is set to change the `AngleX` property from whatever it is now, to `100`, over a period of `0:0:.75` seconds

I'm not that familiar with the [AccelerationRatio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.accelerationratio.aspx) property, however I believe it modifies how fast the value should accelerate from the start value to the end value.

Comment: I'll mark yours as the correct answer because you are pretty. Now why do you think i am getting these error messages  '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(RenderTransform).(0)[1].(1)'? I'm merely copying out the StoryBoard and the TransformGroup and then running the StoryBoard.Begin(), but this error keeps popping out. When I run the demo these errors don't occur.

Comment: @blackeyedpea I'd rather have my answered marked as the correct answer because it's correct :) The error suggests that you are not targeting a `DependencyObject` with your Animation's `TargetProperty` property. My best guess based on the `<DoubleAnimation>` you posted would be that your `<RenderTransform>` does not have a `SkewTransform` as the 2nd object in the collection, but I'm no expert on animations so I could be incorrect. It would help to see your full code for the XAML object.

Comment: here's what i did,using the same code downloaded from the demo,I changed the library into an application,PageTransition class to PageTransition : Window & in the PageTransition xaml, I changed UserControl to Window, & UserControl.Resources to Window.Resources. I then added a button 
`       <Button Content="Animate" Click="Button_Click"/>` 
to the Grid, and defined the Button_Click as 
`        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var story = Resources["FlipOut"] as Storyboard;
            story.Begin(page);
        }
`
I F5 and clicked button.

Comment: lo and behold i got this: '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(RenderTransform).(0)[1].(1)'.

Comment: Since the original demo is meant to be a user control, does changing it to a window have any effect on the TargetProperty?

Comment: @blackeyedpea If you take a look at the `PageTransition.xaml` file for the `PageTransition` control in the source code, you'll see the control defines a set of `RenderTransforms` at the bottom of the page. Your `DoubleAnimation` needs these transformations to exist in order to modify them. You could copy/paste the contents of `<ContentControl.RenderTransform>` to your `<Window.RenderTransform>`, and it would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in a property path that's using the form (X.Y) means "The value of DependencyProperty Y defined in Type X". These can be either normal DPs or attached properties that are set on types other than their owners.